# NetSuite Crypto createHmac showing invalid algorithm value

Tags: netsuite

I am using the crypto module in NetSuite SuiteScript 2.0 . I am using the createHmac method in crypto like below

```
 var hmacSignature = crypto.createHmac({
 algorithm: crypto.HashAlg.SHA1 ,
                     key: sKey
  });
```

I am getting a invalid Type Argument for 'algorithm' value. This is the specified way to set the type as given on NetSuite SuiteScript PDF. What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Where's your code for generating `sKey`?

Comment: I hardcoded the sKey value , since this was a test

Comment: That could be the problem.  The method expects a [crypto.SecretKey object](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/43742). If your hardcoded sKey is not in exactly this format it could create this error.

Comment: Oh okay.. Thanks. Let me try that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Krypton , I could solve this problem by passing a crypto.SecretKey object by generating it using crypto.CreateSecretKey method